# Wp Remote get with manual redirect

Tags: redirect, http, wp-remote-request

I set

```
 add_filter( 'http_request_redirection_count', array($instance,'SetDirectionCount'));
```

to 0

I try to get 'http://boards.ign.com/The_Vestibule/b5296/' or 'http://www.informationweek.com/story/' but that gives me:

```
 WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [http_request_failed] 
 => Array ( [0] => Maximum (0) redirects followed ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )
```

The head does not show me a redirection:

```
Array ( [headers] => Array ( [connection] => close [date] => 
Mon, 14 Mar 2011 01:40:19 GMT [server] => Microsoft-IIS/6.0 [p3p] => Array ( [0] =>  
CP='NOI ADMa OUR STP' [1] => CP="TST" ) [x-powered-by] => ASP.NET [cluster-server] => \      ignprdappw64212 [x-aspnet-version] => 2.0.50727 [pragma] => no-cache [x-aspnetmvc-version] 
=> 1.0 [set-cookie] => BoardCookieV3%5Fboards%2Eign%2Ecom=dc=no&ra=False; expires=Wed,     14-Mar-2012 01:40:19 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly [cache-control] => private [expires] => Wed, 14     
Mar 2001 01:40:19 GMT [content-type] => text/html; charset=utf-8 ) [body] => [response]   =>   
Array ( [code] => 200 [message] => OK ) [cookies] => Array ( [0] => WP_Http_Cookie 
Object ( [name] => BoardCookieV3%5Fboards%2Eign%2Ecom [value] => dc=no&ra=False   
[expires] => 1331689219 [path] => / [domain] => [httponly] => ) ) )
```

Now... what I would have liked is information back from the head request that a 301 or 302 would be happening or even a 404, so that I could wp_remote_get that one instead.

Am I doing something wrong?

FYI: I need to manually redirect because I need to determine the base_href of an image if none is given in the HTML source (code: http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-favicons/trunk/includes/class-http.php ) or some more background: http://wp.leau.co/2011/03/18/handling-redirects-for-wp-favicons-with-redirects-set-to-0-with-wordpress-wp_remote_get/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at the WordPress HTTP API, it seems there ain't no simple way to do this. In fact, it might even be a calling for a trac ticket.

See, although it allows you to specify the maximum number of redirects, there's no abstract option to control if redirects should even be *followed*.

So setting a max redirect count of 0, the HTTP API will simply fail with something like 'Maximum redirects followed'.

<strike>For the time being, you'll need to examine the `request` method of each HTTP transport class (`WP_Http_Curl`, `WP_Http_ExtHttp`...) and look for ideal filters and actions you can use to set the 'nofollow' option for that particular transport.</strike>

On further inspection, I believe only the cURL component of the API is affected;

```
function __set_curl_nofollow( &$handle )
{
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false );  
}
add_action( 'http_api_curl', '__set_curl_nofollow' );
```

<strike>As I mentioned about submitting to trac, I think there should be another option for the API, such as 'follow_redirection', that will then do what it is intended - abstract and take out the hassle!</strike>

[Trac ticket 16855](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16855)

Comment: well.. that WOULD be the best option and then I would not have to write all of this GRIN (see: http://groups.google.com/group/wp-hackers/browse_thread/thread/19dc7c7197f66754/9a60ad0b37ccaf1b?show_docid=9a60ad0b37ccaf1b&pli=1)

Comment: The solution in the ticket adding an extra parameter worked for me. Let's see if / when it gets picked up in a WP Release.