# How to use the HTTP API (wp_remote_get) instead of cURL?

Tags: redirect, curl, http-api, wp-remote-get

I'm running into a problemen while trying to change my cURL request into a request using the HTTP API.

Below code is my (old) cURL request. Here I'm getting some contents from an external URL. This is working perfectly.

**The targeted URL in this example**

```
$myURL = 'https://www.google.com/maps?cid=4493464801819550785';
```

**My cURL request**

```
$ch = curl_init($myURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$pattern = '/window\.APP_INITIALIZATION_STATE(.*);window\.APP_FLAGS=/ms';

if ( preg_match($pattern, $result, $match) ) {
    $match[1]       = trim($match[1], ' =;');
    $output         = json_decode($match[1]);
}

var_dump($output); // SHOWS CONTENTS
```

Now, what I'm trying to accomplish is to use the HTTP API to achieve the same result. I believe the main problem lies in the fact that `$myURL` has a 302 redirect while following. In my cURL request, the use of `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` set to `true` is fixing this problem. The request is following the redirects as it should. Sadly, I cannot find a similar solution for using the HTTP API. Below code is what I have so far.

**My wp_remote_get request**

```
$result = wp_remote_get(
    $myURL,
    array(
        'method'        => 'GET',
        'timeout'       => 45,
        'redirection'   => 10,
        'httpversion'   => '1.0',
        'body'          => array(
            'returnFormat'  => 'json',
        ),
        'sslverify'   => false
    )
);

var_dump($result); // SHOWS CONTENTS FROM A REDIRECTED PAGE
```

**This is the output of `var_dump($result)` (using wp_remote_get)**

```
array(6) {
  ["headers"]=>
  object(Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary)#16709 (1) {
    ["data":protected]=>
    array(18) {
      ["content-type"]=>
      string(24) "text/html; charset=utf-8"
      ["vary"]=>
      string(46) "Sec-Fetch-Dest, Sec-Fetch-Mode, Sec-Fetch-Site"
      ["cache-control"]=>
      string(46) "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
      ["pragma"]=>
      string(8) "no-cache"
      ["expires"]=>
      string(29) "Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
      ["date"]=>
      string(29) "Tue, 16 Aug 2022 08:13:40 GMT"
      ["content-security-policy"]=>
      string(161) "script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-CbZa7ma1grUKc1m413SbUA' 'unsafe-inline';object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';report-uri /_/ConsentHttp/cspreport;worker-src 'self'"
      ["accept-ch"]=>
      string(151) "Sec-CH-UA-Arch, Sec-CH-UA-Bitness, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List, Sec-CH-UA-Model, Sec-CH-UA-Platform, Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version"
      ["cross-origin-opener-policy"]=>
      string(11) "unsafe-none"
      ["content-security-policy-report-only"]=>
      string(70) "require-trusted-types-for 'script';report-uri /_/ConsentHttp/cspreport"
      ["cross-origin-resource-policy"]=>
      string(9) "same-site"
      ["permissions-policy"]=>
      string(137) "ch-ua-arch=*, ch-ua-bitness=*, ch-ua-full-version=*, ch-ua-full-version-list=*, ch-ua-model=*, ch-ua-platform=*, ch-ua-platform-version=*"
      ["content-encoding"]=>
      string(4) "gzip"
      ["server"]=>
      string(3) "ESF"
      ["x-xss-protection"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["x-frame-options"]=>
      string(10) "SAMEORIGIN"
      ["x-content-type-options"]=>
      string(7) "nosniff"
      ["alt-svc"]=>
      string(162) "h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43""
    }
  }
  ["body"]=>
  string(13943) "
Inloggen
Google
Voordat je verdergaat naar Google
We gebruiken cookies en gegevens voor het volgende:
Google-services leveren en onderhouden
Uitval bijhouden en bescherming bieden tegen spam, fraude en misbruik
Doelgroepbetrokkenheid en sitestatistieken meten om inzicht te krijgen in hoe onze services worden gebruikt en de kwaliteit van die services te verbeteren
Als je Alles accepteren kiest, gebruiken we cookies en gegevens ook voor het volgende:
Nieuwe services ontwikkelen en verbeteren
Advertenties laten zien en de effectiviteit ervan meten
Gepersonaliseerde content laten zien (afhankelijk van je instellingen)
Gepersonaliseerde advertenties laten zien (afhankelijk van je instellingen)
Als je Alles afwijzen kiest, gebruiken we cookies niet voor deze aanvullende doeleinden.

Niet-gepersonaliseerde content wordt beïnvloed door factoren zoals de content die je op dat moment bekijkt, activiteit in je actieve zoeksessie en je locatie. Niet-gepersonaliseerde advertenties worden beïnvloed door de content die je op dat moment bekijkt en je algemene locatie. Gepersonaliseerde content en advertenties kunnen ook relevantere resultaten, aanbevelingen en op jou toegespitste advertenties omvatten die zijn gebaseerd op eerdere activiteit van deze browser, zoals uitgevoerde Google-zoekopdrachten. We gebruiken cookies en gegevens ook om te zorgen dat de functionaliteit geschikt is voor je leeftijd, als dit relevant is.

Selecteer Meer opties om meer informatie te bekijken, waaronder informatie over hoe je je privacyinstellingen beheert. Je kunt ook altijd naar g.co/privacytools gaan.
Meer opties

Nederlands
Privacybeleid Servicevoorwaarden
"
  ["response"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["code"]=>
    int(200)
    ["message"]=>
    string(2) "OK"
  }
  ["cookies"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(WP_Http_Cookie)#16701 (7) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "__Secure-ENID"
      ["value"]=>
      string(176) "6.SE=VgGXMbfmNLae_U49j2-xNyX9KSANb6dx9_kBZFAD-livbO1IFRxB0v04PdiGYCunZmFIdgJP9OAoodIXIXhoRNjx66Y0BlVOzVTDco86c0pQty6URPwm9u10tg4KQi3xaer_4s2q3OXLihut8AtZCDWLrFS_eCFQ8l-b67oyaCk"
      ["expires"]=>
      int(1694824318)
      ["path"]=>
      string(1) "/"
      ["domain"]=>
      string(10) "google.com"
      ["port"]=>
      NULL
      ["host_only"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
    [1]=>
    object(WP_Http_Cookie)#16700 (7) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(7) "CONSENT"
      ["value"]=>
      string(11) "PENDING 531"
      ["expires"]=>
      int(1723709620)
      ["path"]=>
      string(1) "/"
      ["domain"]=>
      string(10) "google.com"
      ["port"]=>
      NULL
      ["host_only"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
  }
  ["filename"]=>
  NULL
  ["http_response"]=>
  object(WP_HTTP_Requests_Response)#16713 (5) {
    ["response":protected]=>
    object(Requests_Response)#16710 (10) {
      ["body"]=>
      string(13943) "
Inloggen
Google
Voordat je verdergaat naar Google
We gebruiken cookies en gegevens voor het volgende:
Google-services leveren en onderhouden
Uitval bijhouden en bescherming bieden tegen spam, fraude en misbruik
Doelgroepbetrokkenheid en sitestatistieken meten om inzicht te krijgen in hoe onze services worden gebruikt en de kwaliteit van die services te verbeteren
Als je Alles accepteren kiest, gebruiken we cookies en gegevens ook voor het volgende:
Nieuwe services ontwikkelen en verbeteren
Advertenties laten zien en de effectiviteit ervan meten
Gepersonaliseerde content laten zien (afhankelijk van je instellingen)
Gepersonaliseerde advertenties laten zien (afhankelijk van je instellingen)
Als je Alles afwijzen kiest, gebruiken we cookies niet voor deze aanvullende doeleinden.

Niet-gepersonaliseerde content wordt beïnvloed door factoren zoals de content die je op dat moment bekijkt, activiteit in je actieve zoeksessie en je locatie. Niet-gepersonaliseerde advertenties worden beïnvloed door de content die je op dat moment bekijkt en je algemene locatie. Gepersonaliseerde content en advertenties kunnen ook relevantere resultaten, aanbevelingen en op jou toegespitste advertenties omvatten die zijn gebaseerd op eerdere activiteit van deze browser, zoals uitgevoerde Google-zoekopdrachten. We gebruiken cookies en gegevens ook om te zorgen dat de functionaliteit geschikt is voor je leeftijd, als dit relevant is.

Selecteer Meer opties om meer informatie te bekijken, waaronder informatie over hoe je je privacyinstellingen beheert. Je kunt ook altijd naar g.co/privacytools gaan.
Meer opties

Nederlands
Privacybeleid Servicevoorwaarden
"
      ["raw"]=>
      string(15256) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Vary: Sec-Fetch-Dest, Sec-Fetch-Mode, Sec-Fetch-Site
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Tue, 16 Aug 2022 08:13:40 GMT
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-CbZa7ma1grUKc1m413SbUA' 'unsafe-inline';object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';report-uri /_/ConsentHttp/cspreport;worker-src 'self'
Accept-CH: Sec-CH-UA-Arch, Sec-CH-UA-Bitness, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List, Sec-CH-UA-Model, Sec-CH-UA-Platform, Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: unsafe-none
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: require-trusted-types-for 'script';report-uri /_/ConsentHttp/cspreport
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-site
Permissions-Policy: ch-ua-arch=*, ch-ua-bitness=*, ch-ua-full-version=*, ch-ua-full-version-list=*, ch-ua-model=*, ch-ua-platform=*, ch-ua-platform-version=*
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: ESF
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Inloggen
Google
Voordat je verdergaat naar Google
We gebruiken cookies en gegevens voor het volgende:
Google-services leveren en onderhouden
Uitval bijhouden en bescherming bieden tegen spam, fraude en misbruik
Doelgroepbetrokkenheid en sitestatistieken meten om inzicht te krijgen in hoe onze services worden gebruikt en de kwaliteit van die services te verbeteren
Als je Alles accepteren kiest, gebruiken we cookies en gegevens ook voor het volgende:
Nieuwe services ontwikkelen en verbeteren
Advertenties laten zien en de effectiviteit ervan meten
Gepersonaliseerde content laten zien (afhankelijk van je instellingen)
Gepersonaliseerde advertenties laten zien (afhankelijk van je instellingen)
Als je Alles afwijzen kiest, gebruiken we cookies niet voor deze aanvullende doeleinden.

Niet-gepersonaliseerde content wordt beïnvloed door factoren zoals de content die je op dat moment bekijkt, activiteit in je actieve zoeksessie en je locatie. Niet-gepersonaliseerde advertenties worden beïnvloed door de content die je op dat moment bekijkt en je algemene locatie. Gepersonaliseerde content en advertenties kunnen ook relevantere resultaten, aanbevelingen en op jou toegespitste advertenties omvatten die zijn gebaseerd op eerdere activiteit van deze browser, zoals uitgevoerde Google-zoekopdrachten. We gebruiken cookies en gegevens ook om te zorgen dat de functionaliteit geschikt is voor je leeftijd, als dit relevant is.

Selecteer Meer opties om meer informatie te bekijken, waaronder informatie over hoe je je privacyinstellingen beheert. Je kunt ook altijd naar g.co/privacytools gaan.
Meer opties

Nederlands
Privacybeleid Servicevoorwaarden
"
      ["headers"]=>
      object(Requests_Response_Headers)#16703 (1) {
        ["data":protected]=>
        array(18) {
          ["content-type"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(24) "text/html; charset=utf-8"
          }
          ["vary"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(46) "Sec-Fetch-Dest, Sec-Fetch-Mode, Sec-Fetch-Site"
          }
          ["cache-control"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(46) "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
          }
          ["pragma"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(8) "no-cache"
          }
          ["expires"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(29) "Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
          }
          ["date"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(29) "Tue, 16 Aug 2022 08:13:40 GMT"
          }
          ["content-security-policy"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(161) "script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-CbZa7ma1grUKc1m413SbUA' 'unsafe-inline';object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';report-uri /_/ConsentHttp/cspreport;worker-src 'self'"
          }
          ["accept-ch"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(151) "Sec-CH-UA-Arch, Sec-CH-UA-Bitness, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List, Sec-CH-UA-Model, Sec-CH-UA-Platform, Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version"
          }
          ["cross-origin-opener-policy"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(11) "unsafe-none"
          }
          ["content-security-policy-report-only"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(70) "require-trusted-types-for 'script';report-uri /_/ConsentHttp/cspreport"
          }
          ["cross-origin-resource-policy"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(9) "same-site"
          }
          ["permissions-policy"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(137) "ch-ua-arch=*, ch-ua-bitness=*, ch-ua-full-version=*, ch-ua-full-version-list=*, ch-ua-model=*, ch-ua-platform=*, ch-ua-platform-version=*"
          }
          ["content-encoding"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(4) "gzip"
          }
          ["server"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(3) "ESF"
          }
          ["x-xss-protection"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(1) "0"
          }
          ["x-frame-options"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(10) "SAMEORIGIN"
          }
          ["x-content-type-options"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(7) "nosniff"
          }
          ["alt-svc"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(162) "h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43""
          }
        }
      }
      ["status_code"]=>
      int(200)
      ["protocol_version"]=>
      float(1.1)
      ["success"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["redirects"]=>
      int(1)
      ["url"]=>
      string(129) "https://consent.google.com/ml?continue=https://www.google.com/maps?cid%3D4493464801819550785&gl=NL&m=0&pc=m&uxe=eomtm&hl=nl&src=1"
      ["history"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(Requests_Response)#16712 (10) {
          ["body"]=>
          string(350) "

302 Moved

The document has moved
here.

"
          ["raw"]=>
          string(1863) "HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://consent.google.com/ml?continue=https://www.google.com/maps?cid%3D4493464801819550785&gl=NL&m=0&pc=m&uxe=eomtm&hl=nl&src=1
Cache-Control: private
Timing-Allow-Origin: https://www.google.com
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-jhJkak4vlSBfyfk4tTJ8tQ' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/maps-tactile
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin-allow-popups; report-to="gws"
Report-To: {"group":"gws","max_age":2592000,"endpoints":[{"url":"https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/report-to/gws/maps-tactile"}]}
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
Date: Tue, 16 Aug 2022 08:13:40 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Length: 350
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: __Secure-ENID=6.SE=VgGXMbfmNLae_U49j2-xNyX9KSANb6dx9_kBZFAD-livbO1IFRxB0v04PdiGYCunZmFIdgJP9OAoodIXIXhoRNjx66Y0BlVOzVTDco86c0pQty6URPwm9u10tg4KQi3xaer_4s2q3OXLihut8AtZCDWLrFS_eCFQ8l-b67oyaCk; expires=Sat, 16-Sep-2023 00:31:58 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=lax
Set-Cookie: CONSENT=PENDING+531; expires=Thu, 15-Aug-2024 08:13:40 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Connection: close



302 Moved

The document has moved
here.

"
          ["headers"]=>
          object(Requests_Response_Headers)#16711 (1) {
            ["data":protected]=>
            array(15) {
              ["location"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(129) "https://consent.google.com/ml?continue=https://www.google.com/maps?cid%3D4493464801819550785&gl=NL&m=0&pc=m&uxe=eomtm&hl=nl&src=1"
              }
              ["cache-control"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(7) "private"
              }
              ["timing-allow-origin"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(22) "https://www.google.com"
              }
              ["content-type"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
              }
              ["content-security-policy-report-only"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(210) "object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-jhJkak4vlSBfyfk4tTJ8tQ' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/maps-tactile"
              }
              ["cross-origin-opener-policy"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(41) "same-origin-allow-popups; report-to="gws""
              }
              ["report-to"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(115) "{"group":"gws","max_age":2592000,"endpoints":[{"url":"https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/report-to/gws/maps-tactile"}]}"
              }
              ["p3p"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(62) "CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info.""
              }
              ["date"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(29) "Tue, 16 Aug 2022 08:13:40 GMT"
              }
              ["server"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(3) "gws"
              }
              ["content-length"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(3) "350"
              }
              ["x-xss-protection"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(1) "0"
              }
              ["x-frame-options"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(10) "SAMEORIGIN"
              }
              ["set-cookie"]=>
              array(2) {
                [0]=>
                string(289) "__Secure-ENID=6.SE=VgGXMbfmNLae_U49j2-xNyX9KSANb6dx9_kBZFAD-livbO1IFRxB0v04PdiGYCunZmFIdgJP9OAoodIXIXhoRNjx66Y0BlVOzVTDco86c0pQty6URPwm9u10tg4KQi3xaer_4s2q3OXLihut8AtZCDWLrFS_eCFQ8l-b67oyaCk; expires=Sat, 16-Sep-2023 00:31:58 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=lax"
                [1]=>
                string(94) "CONSENT=PENDING+531; expires=Thu, 15-Aug-2024 08:13:40 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure"
              }
              ["alt-svc"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(162) "h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43""
              }
            }
          }
          ["status_code"]=>
          int(302)
          ["protocol_version"]=>
          float(1.1)
          ["success"]=>
          bool(false)
          ["redirects"]=>
          int(0)
          ["url"]=>
          string(51) "https://www.google.com/maps?cid=4493464801819550785"
          ["history"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["cookies"]=>
          object(Requests_Cookie_Jar)#16714 (1) {
            ["cookies":protected]=>
            array(2) {
              ["__Secure-ENID"]=>
              object(Requests_Cookie)#16707 (5) {
                ["name"]=>
                string(13) "__Secure-ENID"
                ["value"]=>
                string(176) "6.SE=VgGXMbfmNLae_U49j2-xNyX9KSANb6dx9_kBZFAD-livbO1IFRxB0v04PdiGYCunZmFIdgJP9OAoodIXIXhoRNjx66Y0BlVOzVTDco86c0pQty6URPwm9u10tg4KQi3xaer_4s2q3OXLihut8AtZCDWLrFS_eCFQ8l-b67oyaCk"
                ["attributes"]=>
                object(Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary)#16708 (1) {
                  ["data":protected]=>
                  array(6) {
                    ["expires"]=>
                    int(1694824318)
                    ["path"]=>
                    string(1) "/"
                    ["domain"]=>
                    string(10) "google.com"
                    ["secure"]=>
                    bool(true)
                    ["httponly"]=>
                    bool(true)
                    ["samesite"]=>
                    string(3) "lax"
                  }
                }
                ["flags"]=>
                array(4) {
                  ["creation"]=>
                  int(1660637620)
                  ["last-access"]=>
                  int(1660637620)
                  ["persistent"]=>
                  bool(false)
                  ["host-only"]=>
                  bool(false)
                }
                ["reference_time"]=>
                int(1660637620)
              }
              ["CONSENT"]=>
              object(Requests_Cookie)#16706 (5) {
                ["name"]=>
                string(7) "CONSENT"
                ["value"]=>
                string(11) "PENDING+531"
                ["attributes"]=>
                object(Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary)#16705 (1) {
                  ["data":protected]=>
                  array(4) {
                    ["expires"]=>
                    int(1723709620)
                    ["path"]=>
                    string(1) "/"
                    ["domain"]=>
                    string(10) "google.com"
                    ["secure"]=>
                    bool(true)
                  }
                }
                ["flags"]=>
                array(4) {
                  ["creation"]=>
                  int(1660637620)
                  ["last-access"]=>
                  int(1660637620)
                  ["persistent"]=>
                  bool(false)
                  ["host-only"]=>
                  bool(false)
                }
                ["reference_time"]=>
                int(1660637620)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      ["cookies"]=>
      object(Requests_Cookie_Jar)#16714 (1) {
        ["cookies":protected]=>
        array(2) {
          ["__Secure-ENID"]=>
          object(Requests_Cookie)#16707 (5) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(13) "__Secure-ENID"
            ["value"]=>
            string(176) "6.SE=VgGXMbfmNLae_U49j2-xNyX9KSANb6dx9_kBZFAD-livbO1IFRxB0v04PdiGYCunZmFIdgJP9OAoodIXIXhoRNjx66Y0BlVOzVTDco86c0pQty6URPwm9u10tg4KQi3xaer_4s2q3OXLihut8AtZCDWLrFS_eCFQ8l-b67oyaCk"
            ["attributes"]=>
            object(Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary)#16708 (1) {
              ["data":protected]=>
              array(6) {
                ["expires"]=>
                int(1694824318)
                ["path"]=>
                string(1) "/"
                ["domain"]=>
                string(10) "google.com"
                ["secure"]=>
                bool(true)
                ["httponly"]=>
                bool(true)
                ["samesite"]=>
                string(3) "lax"
              }
            }
            ["flags"]=>
            array(4) {
              ["creation"]=>
              int(1660637620)
              ["last-access"]=>
              int(1660637620)
              ["persistent"]=>
              bool(false)
              ["host-only"]=>
              bool(false)
            }
            ["reference_time"]=>
            int(1660637620)
          }
          ["CONSENT"]=>
          object(Requests_Cookie)#16706 (5) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(7) "CONSENT"
            ["value"]=>
            string(11) "PENDING+531"
            ["attributes"]=>
            object(Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary)#16705 (1) {
              ["data":protected]=>
              array(4) {
                ["expires"]=>
                int(1723709620)
                ["path"]=>
                string(1) "/"
                ["domain"]=>
                string(10) "google.com"
                ["secure"]=>
                bool(true)
              }
            }
            ["flags"]=>
            array(4) {
              ["creation"]=>
              int(1660637620)
              ["last-access"]=>
              int(1660637620)
              ["persistent"]=>
              bool(false)
              ["host-only"]=>
              bool(false)
            }
            ["reference_time"]=>
            int(1660637620)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    ["filename":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["data"]=>
    NULL
    ["headers"]=>
    NULL
    ["status"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

So, in above example, the `var_dump` outputs an array of data, but not for the given URL. It shows data from the (302) redirected URL.

How can I achieve the same result as I did with cURL and `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`?

Comment: Just to be clear - you're saying that the `var_dump($result)` in the second code block is producing data corresponding to the `302` response itself rather than that of the final redirected destination? The `redirection` argument you've supplied *should* be following up to 5 redirection responses - have you tested the request via some other means to examine if it is redirected more than 5 times?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you should correct the `'sslverify'   => 'false'` - because it should actually be `'sslverify'   => false`, i.e. not the string `'false'` which is equivalent to a `true`. Also, redirections can be followed by setting the `redirection` to a non-zero number, which you've already done it, so what's the full output of `var_dump($result);` ? (just replace sensitive URLs and other data with dummy ones)

Comment: Note though that not all HTTP transports support redirections, but as far as I know, the core ones (`curl` and `streams`) do support redirections - and the default transport is cURL, but then the [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is (always) set to `false`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.0.1/wp-includes/class-wp-http-curl.php#L141-L145).

Comment: @bosco, yes that's exactly what is happening. The `var_dump` is showing data of the redirected URL instead of the actually targeted URL. The 302 redirect is a cookie consent page. With `cURL` and `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` set to `true`, the targeted page is being called correctly. Are there additional steps I need to take using the `HTTP API` or am I missing something here?

Comment: Honestly your code roughly looks like a fairly accurate translation of your cURL code. There are definitely some discrepancies - but in my experience most web servers do not care about those differences. I asked about testing the request externally to examine how many redirects actually occur in the course of resolving the request because that seems like a possible candidate for a problem to me, at least to begin with. Without being able to test the destination URL and request ourselves (which is totally reasonable if it is in any way confidential), guiding you to test it is all we can do.

Comment: @SallyCJ well that's a fascinating line. It seems to me that the `cURL` transport is selected in most instances, and I swear that I've seen `wp_remote_get()` resolve redirects in the past... but maybe I'm mistaken, or maybe I did something which invoked stream transport instead... Or I'm just misremembering. Do you suppose it's necessary to manually resolve redirects in the case that the `cURL` transport is selected, then? I'll Google around a bit.

Comment: @bosco cURL is the default transport, and so long as `redirection` is enabled, then redirection will be followed - internally via WordPress' own redirects handler, even if `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is `false`. So I don't know why would it not work when the code in question is good (except the `sslverify` part). But I'd probably try adding the `returnFormat` parameter as a query string.

Comment: @SallyCJ, you were right about the `'false'` after `'sslverify'`. I've fixed this and edited my question, but that wasn't the issue. In my edited question I've now posted a URL with the corresponding `var_dump` response I get back using `wp_remote_get`. As you can see the response is of the 302 redirected URL instead of the targeted URL. Exactly that response is happening in my cURL request too when I set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to `false`.

Comment: @DeltaG the response looked good to me - WordPress did follow the redirect there (check the items keyed `redirects` and `history` respectively). But it's probably a Google consent issue... Or you didn't send the correct parameters and thus the second page halted with a message instead (no `Location` header). Try comparing both the request and response when using the `curl_xx` functions and when using `wp_remote_get()`, and you'd know what is/are missing. Have you tried adding the user-agent header to your `wp_remote_get()` args?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like I've managed to fix my own problem here. I don't know if this is the best thinkable solution to this exact problem, but it does work!

My assumptions about `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` seem correct. As *Sally CJ* also explained in the comments, the default setting in WP is always set to `false`. That's why the data always contained contents from the (302) redirect instead of the actual targeted URL.

I've found [this old thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/11964/168537) and answer where the underlying `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is changed through the `http_api_curl` action. Using this action to override the default setting was the key for fixing my problem with `wp_remote_get`. With the function enabled (see below), my returned data is exactly the same as when using cURL.

```
function __set_curl_to_follow( &$handle ) {
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );  
}
add_action( 'http_api_curl', '__set_curl_to_follow' );
```

Special thanks to Sally CJ and bosco for thinking with me on this!

Comment: You're very welcome, but actually, just now I tried the exact same `wp_remote_get()` code in question and also used the same Google maps URL, and everything worked fine for me, and even after setting `redirection` to `0`, I still received the correct response (a Google map page), both without having to force `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to `true`. So I wondered what exactly happened in your case, or the real reason why that cURL option had to be `true`. As for the sample response though, it looked like a cookie issue, so not sure if WordPress was at fault. 

Comment: Nonetheless, I'm glad you managed to find the filter on your own - which BTW, I deliberately didn't mention in the comments, because in normal situations, using the filter isn't necessary for the purpose of following redirections - so if I were you, I'd try to investigate further to check if this was a core bug.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working! I never would have thought that such a thing would be necessary - definitely super curious as to what's going on there. If you do pursue it any further, please report back with your findings :)